# Are callbacks important in an Alexa skill?

Tags: node.js, callback, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to understand how to use Node.js callbacks specifically why and when you would use them in an Alexa skill.
The highlow game sample https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-highlowgameuses employs a callback when the correct number has been guessed but
if I move the callback code into the NumberGuessIntent function the the skill appears to behave exactly the same so what is the purpose of that callback?

Code without a callback:

```
'NumberGuessIntent': function() {
        var guessNum = parseInt(this.event.request.intent.slots.number.value);
        var targetNum = this.attributes["guessNumber"];
        console.log('user guessed: ' + guessNum);

        if(guessNum > targetNum){
            this.emit('TooHigh', guessNum);
        } else if( guessNum < targetNum){
            this.emit('TooLow', guessNum);
        } else if (guessNum === targetNum){
            this.handler.state = states.STARTMODE;
            this.attributes['gamesPlayed']++;
            this.emit(':ask', guessNum.toString() + 'is correct! Would you like to play a new game?',
                'Say yes to start a new game, or no to end the game.');
        } else {
            this.emit('NotANum');
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are used for async operations such as fetching data from a Web API.

It will be easier for you to use Promises that like you execute async operation exactly as you would run sync code. See more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises